# How to create a pandas DataFrame with specified number of rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to the pandas concept. Is it possible to create a DataFrame of size 1 row and column-length of 8?

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':[]})
```

But this only creates one row and one column.

Comment: Yes it is possible to create any shape dataframe.

Comment: How to do that, because with this i can create only 1 row and 1 column.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':[]})

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_records([[None]*8])` for example

Answer (score 20):

You can specify both `index` and `columns` to determine the shape. Values will default to `NaN`.

```
pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(1), columns=np.arange(8))
```

#### Output

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible to create a dataframe of any shape. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size=(1,8)))
```

Yields:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  1  5  2  3  4  8  7  1
```

Then we can return the shape of this dataframe using `df.shape`:

```
(1, 8)
```

Comment: Hi,
is it possible to do something like this.
dr = pd.DataFrame({'Data':[]}) of size(1,8). I meant to merge all the columns in one row with only one value.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, please update your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Just extend pault's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53104048/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-with-specified-number-of-rows-and-columns#comment93103785_53104048) with arbitrary rows and columns.

```py
row, col = 2, 3

out = pd.DataFrame.from_records([[None]*col]*row)
```

```
print(out)

      0     1     2
0  None  None  None
1  None  None  None
```

If you want to specify the column header, you can use `columns` parameter.

```py
out = pd.DataFrame.from_records([[None]*col]*row,
                                columns=list('abc'))
```

```
print(out)

      a     b     c
0  None  None  None
1  None  None  None
```